# How to detect if not western language in classic asp string from db?

Tags: asp-classic

I have both "western" languages and "eastern" languages in my db.
I use a mysql database and classic asp to get the data and display it.

So when I display "eastern" languages I want to right align the text.

And only for those "eastern" languages that are right aligned, I don´t know if all "eastern" languages are right aligned!?

So can I detect if the string from the db is an "eastern" language? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What *"western languages"* are right aligned? I suppose it depends where you are from but in terms of right aligned languages usually it refers to the [Right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) in various [writing systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system) used by a lot of "eastern" languages *(arabic script etc.)*.

Comment: "I guess not all NONE western are right aligned!?" ;-) This is a page in Sweden and the user is in Sweden as well, so you can´t detect it from where the user are. I need to check it from the database if that´s possible!?

Comment: Check what, still not understanding what you are trying to achieve? Again you mention *"western"*, which *"western"* languages do you consider should be right aligned? Like I have already mentioned right alignment is usually used in relation to RTL languages like Arabic script for example. Are you just talking about personal formatting preference? It's hard to decipher what you are trying to do.

Comment: No western languages should be right aligned, I think you miss read.
Im trying to check if the language in the string from the db are in eg Arabic(none western), then I can right align the text.

Comment: Ok so I have edit my question :-)

Comment: Right ok, now that makes sense. In the past I've done this by having a column in the table in my database called `[rtl]` which is usually just a bit field for `true` or `false` and when storing the language data I lookup the `[rtl]` value to determine if it needs to be right aligned.

Comment: Ok, thanks, thats just what I have thought I had to do, and I just wondered if there was another way to detect it.

Comment: Just found out that all you have to do is to set dir=auto on input fields and on the divs displaying the text and it will display eastern languages correct!